# Not able to get Opportunity merge fields in SingleEmailMessage in Apex class

Tags: community

```
 String query = 'select id,OwnerId,Contact__c,Contact__r.name,Contact__r.Language__c,AccountId,Account.ownerId, name,CloseDate,lastmodifieddate,Total_VMA__c,StageName from Opportunity where StageName in (\'Potential\') limit 1';
List < Opportunity > opptyList = Database.Query(query);
List < Task > tasks = new List < Task > ();
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] theEmails = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {};
EmailTemplate objTemp = [SELECT Id FROM EmailTemplate where DeveloperName = 'TASK_and_EMAIL_TO_OPPORTUNITY_OWNER_BEFORE_OPPORTUNITY_CLOSE_DATE'
 limit 1
];
for (Opportunity opp: opptyList) {
 if (opp.closeDate == Date.today()) {
  Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
  string[] toAdd = new string[] {
   'ext-pallavi.sharma@elisa.fi'
  };
  String[] toAddress = new String[] {};
  toAddress.add(opp.ownerId);
  toAddress.add(opp.Account.ownerId);
  mail.setToAddresses(toAdd);
  mail.setTemplateId(objTemp.id);
  mail.setTargetObjectId(opp.Contact__c);
  mail.setTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient(true);
  mail.setWhatId(opp.id);
  mail.saveAsActivity = false;
  theEmails.add(mail);
```

It gives error :

> System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0;
>   first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Missing targetObjectId with
>   template: []

Comment: Your using template? i think mail.setTargetObjectId(opp.Contact__c)!! it's required if your using templates.

Comment: yes, I am using Email template on Opportunity object.

Comment: I have to use Opportunity merge fields. How do I bypass this constraint of using contact, lead or user? I have added Contact for same sake, but now it gives error that tempate is missing for targetobjectid that means Contact..

Answer (score 1):

Your email template can have two records available to it to populate merge fields - the `WhoId`, which here is the same as your Target Object Id because you've called `setTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient()`, and the `WhatId`, which is called Related To in the UI.

Since you're populating your Opportunity record as the `WhatId`, you can access its fields through the Related merge tree. You don't need it to be the target object, and it can't be - the target object [must be](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm#!)

> The ID of the contact, lead, or user to which the email will be sent.

However, you seem to have a different issue here, because you're getting

> System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Missing targetObjectId with template: []

This suggests to me that `Opportunity.Contact__c` is `null`, which your code should definitely validate before attempting to send the email.